# how to check whether data is returned or not in android?

Tags: android

I'm making an application in which I have to do XML parsing.

I have to check if the user is able to access new data only then I have to delete the old data in the database.

For the above I am using the following code:

```
try{
      URL url = new URL(address);
      /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
      SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
      /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
      XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
      /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader */
      xr.setContentHandler(this);
      /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
      InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
      //once data is obtained then delete the table.
      hb.executeSql("DELETE FROM Products,Category");
      xr.parse(is);
 }
 catch{
   e.printstacktrace();
 }
```

If there is an error in the input stream then an exception will be thrown which I'm catching and the code for deleting the table will never be executed.

Is the logic correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, if url.OpenStream() throws an exception you would catch it. But to be completely on the safe side, you need to put

```
xr.parse(is);
```

before

```
hb.exequteSql("Delete...");
```

Because xr.parse could throw an IO or SAX exception, and your code would delete even if that happens.

for API, please see

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)

Also i would recommend you catch, IO and SAX exceptions seperately. It would help you debug things easily.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch block is wrong. see handling exceptions in java.

the syntax is:

```
try{
// do your logic here.

}catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
// do something if there is or isnt an exception
}
```

if there is an exception it will skip to the catch code which means you can add your code for deleting the old data as the last line before the catch block then if everything above it runs without an exception your code will execute, otherwise at the point of the exception it will skip everything to the catch block and then when the catch is completed it will go to the finally block and leave the try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to parse xml by using android SAXParser.this link contain how to parse an xml

http://www.ctctlabs.com/index.php/blog/detail/parsing_xml_on_android/

Answer (score 0):

use tbelow function this function returns boolean value.

```
public boolean parseResultantXml(String handlerType,String inputXml){
        boolean result = false;
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp;
        XMLReader xr = null;
        try {
            sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SAXParsersUtil saxParserUtil = new SAXParsersUtil();

        RequiredParser rp = saxParserUtil.getParser(handlerType);
        xr.setContentHandler(rp);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + inputXml)
                            .getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }
        try {
            xr.parse(new InputSource(in));
            result = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```